# javascript/angular change URL before refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with items that each item has an ID.
When selecting an item, I'm changing the URL using angular $location.search to look something like this:

```
http://domain/all-items//?id=55f57cbe5e49356039839d32
```

I'm doing it so users will be able to copy this URL and send it to their colleagues.
When navigating to this kind of URL, it shows the correct item.

The problem happens when refreshing the page.
When I'm refreshing, I don't want the page to select the unique item, I want it to show all items, that's why I need the URL to be:

```
http://domain/all-items//
```

or even:

```
http://domain/all-items//?id=
```

before refreshing the page.

I tried to do it using angular's:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                $location.search('id', '');
            };
```

(also with `$location.search('id', null`) )

But it doesn't do anything.

All I found while searching for answers is how to change the URL without refreshing the page, what I need is how to change the URL before refreshing the page.

Comment: I think you can do with ui-router, with notify: false

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) alludes to using `null`

```
$location.search('id', null);
```